# Poisson Process independent Wiener Process using singular measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes, singular-measures

I was reading some stochastic calculus of Jump processes and saw the following result:

> If $W_t$ is Brownian and $N_t$ is Poisson both adapted to the $W_t$'s natural filtration then these processes are independent.

The book went on to give a stochastic calculus argument.

I was curious couldn't we just prove this by using the fact that the increments of $W_t$ is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure $m$ and the increments of $N_t$ are absolutely continuous wrt the counting measure $c$ which is singular wrt $m$....

This is just an intuition but I do not know how to approach the proof.  So I'm asking here...

Comment: They may be as depended as one wants. Did you mean that their laws are singular?

Comment: Yes their laws are singular.

Comment: The accepted answer misses the point (probably because of the wrong assertion in the first comment above by the same user) and the result mentioned in your post, albeit surprising at first sight, actually holds. The key assumption is that $N$ must be adapted to the natural filtration of $W$. For a proof, see the accepted answer [there](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57808/correlated-brownian-motion-and-poisson-process) (or George Lowther's answer on the same MO page, but not the two others which miss the point). Tricky stuff, eh...

Comment: @Did, thanks, this cleared this for me. I was answering the first version of this question, which was quite different. I will edit something in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the singularity of their laws has nothing to do with the singularity of the Lebesgue and counting measures.

There are many ways to show this singularity. The simplest is to say that the paths of $N$ live in $\mathbb{Z}^{[0,+\infty)}$, while those of $W$ belong here with probability $0$, whence the required singularity follows.

---

Now concerning the independence. Though the links given in the comments are relevant, there is some confusion. In particular, I believe that the accepted answer of @kakaritsu [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57808/correlated-brownian-motion-and-poisson-process) is wrong. Below I will comment on this.

First of all, the statement is absurd as it is written now. The Poisson process cannot be at the same time adapted to the natural filtration of $W_t$ and be independent of it. No way.

Let us try to formulate the true statement. The obvious alternative is

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal F_t\},\mathsf P)$ be a filtered probability space, and let the processes $W$ (Wiener), $N$ (Poisson) be $\mathbb F$-adapted. Then they are independent.

Still wrong. The problem with this formulation is that any couple of processes is adapted to some filtration. Ok, let us try something better. Namely, call a process $W$  $\mathbb F$-Wiener if 1) it is a Wiener process; 2) it is $\mathbb F$-adapted; 3) for each $t>0$, the increments of $W$ after $t$ are independent of $\mathcal F_t$. A $\mathbb F$-Poisson process is defined similarly. Now a reasonable alternative is:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal F_t\},\mathsf P)$ be a filtered probability space, and let the processes $W$, $N$ be $\mathbb F$-Wiener and $\mathbb F$-Poisson. Then they are independent.

It is hard to believe, but this is still wrong. The reason is following: despite $W_s-W_t$ and $N_s-N_t$ are independent of $\mathcal F_t$ for $s\ge t$, the pair $(W_s-W_t,N_s-N_t)$ can depend on it! So the true formulation is:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal F_t\},\mathsf P)$ be a filtered probability space, and let $W$, $N$ be $\mathbb F$-adapted Wiener and Poisson processes *such that $(W_s-W_t,N_s-N_t)$ is independent from $\mathcal F_t$ for each $0<t<s$*. Then $W$ and $N$ are independent.

Alternatively, one can forget about the stochastic basis and formulate it as follows:

> Let the processes $W$, $N$ be Wiener and Poisson *such that $(W,N)$ has independent increments*. Then $W$ and $N$ are independent.

The both last statements are correct, see Kallenberg Lemma 13.6 for the proof.

Now why I think the above cited answer is incorrect (and it was criticized for this by @Did). In fact, the answerer refers to the Ito formula (nothing is wrong here) and then claims that $L$ is a martingale. And the last is wrong in general. For that one need some extra assumptions like those in the last two formulations.

I may be wrong somewhere, so any comments (@Did, if you please?) are welcome.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: See my comment on main.

Comment: You misread big time: one considers $W$ a Brownian motion and $N$ a Poisson process both for a given filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ *which is a priori neither the natural filtration of $W$, nor of $N$*. In particular $W$ and $N$ are adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$ but this is not the only condition (let me assume you know what being a Brownian motion or a Poisson process for a given filtration entails) and your very first objection is moot: $N$ is at the same time adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ (which is not a priori the natural filtration of $W$) and independent of $W$. Hope this helps.

Comment: For some more context, recall that $W$ being a Brownian motion in its own filtration $(\mathcal F^W_t)$ does not entail that $W$ is a Brownian motion in every larger filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$. Here, the (strong) hypothesis is that $W$ is a Brownian motion in $(\mathcal F_t)$, not only in $(\mathcal F^W_t)$, and that $(\mathcal F_t)$ is large enough for the similar hypothesis on $N$ to hold.

Comment: Ok, I see your point (and I need to admit that I didn't read MO past the accepted answer for excellent Lowther's input). Anyway, I see "natural" written in the original post quite clearly, so the statement is still absurd?